# Windows 2019 server on Azure, SQL memory crash

Tags: windows, iis, sql-server, azure, memory

I'm running a website on Azure, I've got my own VM with Windows 2019, MSSQL server and IIS installed.

This is the second time the following happend now in about 3 months. The website has been up for a couple of months, and then suddenly the following:

Getting an error on the frontend (website)

```
Server error in application: No process is on the other end of the pipe -SQL Exception: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake.
```

When trying to log on  the server by RDP I get a protocol error: 0x112f

The only thing I can do is restart from the Azure portal. After logging in again I checked the logs and there was a gigantic list of the following errors:

```
 ERROR: Source MSSQLSERVER: Error: 17300, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
```

All of this combined has led to me thinking my SQL ran out of memory, or is suddenly hogging ALL memory, disallowing any new connections. But I can sadly not find any resolution as of yet..

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you look at the Azure Monitor stats for the VM to see if it is running out of memory?

Comment: As alternative, configure Windows perfromance counters and let VM be monitored for some period of time.